# How to replace an unknown string? (only pattern is known)

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to replace a string which might appear within a URL.

The string has the following pattern:

`%26TID%3D123456`

1. I want to replace the `123456` part, to a specific value such as: `777777`.
2. To be on the safe side though, I don't want to assume that the relevant part of the original string has necessarily 6 digits after the `%3D` part; I want to assume that the original string might contain a few more or few less characters (and I also can't tell the real value of each digit).
3. In addition, when I replace the string, since that string will usually appear in the middle of the URL, I need to replace it without modifying the rest of the URL. After that string, there would usually be another `%26` string which I want to keep including whatever that is after it, but to be on the safe side, I don't want to assume that the original string is necessarily followed by `%26`.

What is the best practice to make such a replacement, that would stand up to all my above conditions?

Comment: Well you already tagged your question with the best practice imho: Use regular expressions (regex). Have you tried anything like that? If so, what exactly? And what results did you get? How did they vary from your expectation? Regular expressions can also be used to make replacements in PHP, see [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: It seems you have encoded key-value pairs in your url as `%26` is `&` and `%3D` is `=`. So you should probably parse the string, get and modify the keys or values that you need to modify and encode it again.

Comment: @ArSeN actually I don't really know how to use `regex` function :/

Comment: @rockyraw then here is your chance to learn about it. Read some tutorials, read the examples in the PHP manual. Fiddle around with it. I can highly recommend [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for fiddling around. Or pay someone to do the job, just don't expect someone here to do your work for free :)

Comment: You said that 123456 would be replaced with 777777, but that there won't necessarily be six digits in the original string. So would you replace 1234 with 777777 or 7777?

Comment: And I'll echo what @ArSeN said. You should read up on regex and take a shot at this problem. I think "why does my solution not work?" is more well received than "how do I do this?" here on SO. And regex are pretty fundamental, so you would do well to learn about them.

Comment: @PatrickLee `1234` shall be replaced with `777777` (basically, it means that the replacment value is a constant that will be defined in the code, e.g., $constant="777777")

Comment: @ArSeN I can try reading, but the bigger point that I'm not sure that what I want is possible: If on one hand, I don't want to put a hard limit on the number of characters, and on the other hand, I don't want to assume that the last relevant character will be followed by a certain string such as `%26`, maybe I must give up on one of these conditions? that's not something that I can find out on a tutorial :)

Comment: @rockyraw I can assure you that it's possible. Just a little bit tricky.

Comment: @rockyraw I agree with PatrickLee and can also assure you that it is possible. As a matter of fact a skilled regex writer can most likely do it within a few minutes. Have fun with the challenge! (And of course feel free to report back with your approaches, so people can give you hints on where you are still a bit wrong)

Comment: @PatrickLee But I do have to assume something in order to define the boundaries of what I want to replace, don't I? the only thing that comes to my mind is that maybe I should require that the boundary will check if the characters are in the form of *digits*. Though can't tell if this is best practice.

Comment: You're on the right track. Hint: `[^\d]` is any non-digit character.

Comment: @rockyraw: The task is not trivial as some have mentioned. People get frantic seeing lazy dot matching in work and that is a basic regex thing. I suspect you are looking for a `\G` based regex. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG4uU6/1).

Comment: @stribizhev I guess I didn't make myself clear enough, `77777` might as well be `320428` or `504732`, I don't mean that I want to replace each digit with the same digit. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then, are you just looking for something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/iG4uU6/2)? Also, do you mean to just replace the first occurrence in the string?

Comment: @stribizhev more or less this is what I need, but the string `TID` must be present right before the value that is to be replaced. your example works on `PID` for example as well, so it's too broad. Since such occurrence is expected only once, then yes, first occurence is enough.

Comment: You can add it to the loobehind. Or just use [`'~(%26TID%3D)\d+~'`](http://ideone.com/OlexFw).

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks I used `/(?<=TID%3D)\\d+/` and it worked. 1) what's the difference between this and your suggestion: `~(%26TID%3D)\d+~`? 2) There's no way to achieve what I want unless I necessarily make such a digits reference within the code, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is to specify the boundary (or an "anchor") (here, a starting one) and then match whatever you want with the more generic pattern.

Here,  the "anchor" is the literal text `TID%3D`. The more generic pattern is one or more digits: `\d+`.

Since you need to replace the first occurrence,  you need to pass `1` as the *limit* argument value in `preg_replace`.

So, combining all that:

```
$re = '~TID%3D\d+~'; 
$str = "%26TID%3D123456 %26PID%3D123456 %26TID%3D123456"; 
$subst = 'TID%3D7652'; 
echo $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
// = > %26TID%3D7652 %26PID%3D123456 %26TID%3D123456
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/YR1f3z)

If you do not want (or do not know) the "anchor" text, use a capturing mechanism ([demo](http://ideone.com/xro3Pv)):

```
$re = '~(TID%\w{2})\d+~'; // (...) specify a capturing group referenced with ${1} later 
$str = "%26TID%3D123456 %26PID%3D123456 %26TID%3D123456"; 
$subst = '${1}7652'; 
echo $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
// = > %26TID%3D7652 %26PID%3D123456 %26TID%3D123456
```

You can also use a [lookbehind approach](http://ideone.com/mg2O6m), but it is less efficient:

```
$re = '~(?<=TID%3D)\d+~';  // (?<=TID%3D) makes sure digits are preceded with TID%3D substring
$str = "%26TID%3D123456 %26PID%3D123456 %26TID%3D123456"; 
$subst = '${1}7652'; 
echo $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```